# Android, issue with missing constraints for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I newish to Android and I have the following XML element

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="#1"
    android:textColor="#006600"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

I am not sure which one am I missing?

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Missing constraints is caused if an element is inside a ConstraintLayout but does not have the constraints set.

You can either set the height and width to **matchParent** to avoid setting constraints.

If that's not the case then you can set the constraints like below

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/rank"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="#1"
android:textColor="#006600"
android:textSize="40sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingStart="15dp"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```